how Menu should be imported correctly in `preload`?
Under the preload/index.ts directory:
I imported {Menu} from "electron"; however, when I printed Menu, it turned out to be undefined.
import { Menu, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';

console.log('imported status: ', Menu, ipcRenderer)  // the Menu: undefined, the ipcRenderer has value

Could you please tell me how it should be imported correctly?
my electron version: "electron": "^31.0.2",

As stated on the docs of Menu, it is only available on the main process. Thus, you can't import it on the preload. If you need to interact with the menu, initialize it on main, and use IPC to communicate between your processes.
